# How to enable VT-x/AMD-v in Aspire V5-122P bios?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization

I have been trying to download and run Back track Linux 5 r3 on my windows 8.1 (AMD Quad-Core processor, 64bit Intel.) using Virtual Box. It kept giving me the error "This Kernel requires an x86-64 bit cpu but only detected an i686 cpu so I downgraded to 4.2 Virtual Box. That solved the problem but now I keep getting an error when I run Virtual Box linux with Ubuntu 64 bit "VT-x/AMD-v hardware acceleration is enabled but not operational. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit cpu and will fail to boot. Please ensure that you have enabled VT-x/AMD-v properly in the bios of your host computer." I have searched and digged through the internet and found nothing useful to my predicament. How can I enable VT-x/AMD-v in my windows 8.1 bios so I can run Back Track Linux properly? Ive looked through my bios and found nothing relevant to Virtualization or VT-x/AMD-v so I came here. Thanks :D

Comment: This really depends on your computer model and bios type. specifying them may help answering the question

Comment: I suspect your CPU does not support VT-x/AMD-v. You can right click the task bar in your windows 8.1 and select "task manager". Go to the "performance tab". On that tab, you can see your CPU model and whether  the virtualization is enabled or not, like the screenshot on this [page](http://www.solvusoft.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Windows-8.1-Task-Manager-Task-Manager-Expanded-SolvuSoft.png)

Comment: Yea you're right. it says its disabled. What should I do?

Comment: drorb my bios version is inside corp. V2.02, 4/16/2013 and the bios type is UEFI, my system model is Aspire V5-122P. My system says that Hyper-V Virtualization is not enabled. And also on taks manager (thanks to Robin) it says Virtualization is disabled. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the support for enabling AMD visualization (SVM) is hidden in the advanced bios features. This [thread](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/45118-Acer-Aspire-V5-122p-Enable-SVM-How-To) explains how to expose the hidden "advanced features" in your bios.
This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Q8aOFKts7s) shows the hidden advanced features in the Acer Aspire V5-122p bios, including AMD-Virtualization Technology @1:48.

Comment: The difference between my BIOS and the person's BIOS in the video, is that for some weird reason I don't have an "Advanced" tab. And I don't have as many enable/disable options as he does. Why is this? I have the exact same bios version and exact same computer model.

Comment: You can expose the hidden "advanced settings" by following the instructions in the 2nd link in my answer, however it is not a trivial process.

Comment: the thread you posted is quiet confusing... anybody have a video or can make one to help me?

Comment: I tried this about 6 months ago and it didn't work. Finally got around to trying again today and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Windows 8.1 uses Hyper-V itself by default for some reasons, so VirtualBox is not capable to use it too. You can force Windows 8.1 not to use Hyper-V. Just run 'cmd.exe' with administrator rights and type:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

But it may cause some lags in work of Windows UI. So, to turn it back, type:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype on
```

**Don't forget to restart your computer after these actions.**