# Cannot Use Android Emulator because of VT-x

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

I been having a problem with android emulators on both Android Studio and Eclipse. I cannot get it to run becuase the Intel HAXM is not installed. I installed it via the sdk manager but still cannot run the intelhaxm.exe. because VT-x needs to be enabled but I don't know how to do that on an Acer Aspire since its blocked off in the bios. Is there a way to get around this? Thank you.

Comment: Other than to replace the PC, or perhaps upgrade the BIOS to one that allows VT-x, I do not think there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if support for VT-x is may be found in the advanced BIOS features. There is a thread that discusses this topic, along with providing a tutorial on how to expose the "hidden" BIOS features, may be found here: [How to enable VT-x/AMD-v in Aspire V5-122P bios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770494/how-to-enable-vt-x-amd-v-in-aspire-v5-122p-bios)